# How does uniswap upgrade its smart contract given that smart contract are immutable once deployed?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, uniswap

In my understanding, smart contracts on Ethereum are immutable once they are pushed onto chain. Then how does uniswap keeps upgrading itself from v1 to v2 to v3? How can they modify their smart contract code? "They" here apparently refer to Uniswap Labs. Additionally, since it is decentralized and nothing is special about Uniswap Labs, can anyone else modify the Uniswap contract as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each version of Uniswap is a different set of contracts, deployed on different addresses. So there is no upgrading of existing contracts. See the links for the list of addresses:

- v1: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V1/guides/connect-to-uniswap#factory-address
- v2: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/factory
- v3: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/deployments

---

Besides this approach of deploying each version to a new address, there's also the proxy pattern. Similarly to networking proxies, you can redirect the request to a target contract, and possibly modify it along the way. If the target address is stored in a variable, you can change the value without changing the actual contract bytecode.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Proxy {
    address target;

    function setTarget(address _target) external {
        // you can change the value of `target` variable in storage
        // without chanding the `Proxy` contract bytecode
        target = _target;
    }

    fallback(bytes calldata) external returns (bytes memory) {
        (bool success, bytes memory returnedData) = target.delegatecall(msg.data);
        require(success);
        return returnedData;
    }
}
```

You can read more about the upgradable proxy pattern here: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies

Note that my code above is simplified to showcase just the basic proxy functionality. It is vulnerable to storage collision mentioned in the article, as well as to [Delegatecall to Untrusted Callee](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-112).

Comment: In addition to the multiple "global" versions of Uniswap, there are also some components that have multiple versions on their own, for example there is UniswapV2Router01 and UniswapV2Router02, the latter deployed in a different address.

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation! Does this mean that except for moral standard/community honor code,  objectively there is nothing to stop Uniswap Labs from modifying how uniswap's smart contract works whenever they want to?

Comment: @manner_teacher If their contracts were upgradable proxies, they would be able to only partially change existing functions because the storage collision would break most of the changes. But they would be able to easily append new functions without removing the old ones... Generally speaking, when you have an app with upgradable proxy, it is technically possible to add malicious functions that were not there before. For such as large organization as Uniswap, even having possibility of doing this might be a reputational hazard, so I'm guessing that they didn't implement this approach on purpose.

Comment: thanks but could you explain a bit more what you mean by "storage collision"?

Comment: @manner_teacher The proxy pattern uses code of the target but storage of the proxy... Example: Proxy contract stores a value (e.g. the `target` address) in storage slot 0. The target contract stores a different value (e.g. a `favoriteNumber` integer) also in slot 0. If the target contract implements some `setFavoriteNumber()` function and you invoke it **through the proxy**, it overwrites the slot 0 **on the proxy** contract... So your intention was to change the `favoriteNumber` on the target contract but you effectively changed the `target` variable on the `proxy` contract.